# Why am I facing "The type or namespace name 'UnitTestClassBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests

I am using Testleft to automate test scenarios.

Using VS for the 1st time.

This is the code:

```
############################################################################
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SmartBear.TestLeft;
using SmartBear.TestLeft.TestObjects;
using SmartBear.TestLeft.TestObjects.Win;
using System.IO;

namespace TestLeftProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestLeftTest : UnitTestClassBase
    {
        #region Class initializers
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
        {
            UnitTestClassBase.InitializeClass(context);
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanUp()
        {
            UnitTestClassBase.FinalizeClass();
        }
        #endregion

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Runs the Notepad application
            IProcess process = Driver.Applications.Run("notepad.exe");

            // Gets Notepad's edit box
            IWinTextEdit edit = process.Find<ITopLevelWindow>(new WindowPattern()
            {
                WndClass = "Notepad"
            }).Find<IWinTextEdit>(new WindowPattern()
            {
                WndClass = "Edit"
            });

            // Simulates a mouse click in Notepad
            edit.Click();

            // Simulates text input in Notepad
            string inputText = "test";
            edit.SetText(inputText);

            // Verifies the text that Notepad contains
            Assert.AreEqual(inputText, edit.wText);

            // Posts messages to the TestLeft test log
            Driver.Log.Screenshot(edit, "Notepad's edit box screenshot");
            Driver.Log.Warning("A warning message");

            // Saves the TestLeft test log
            string logPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_H_mm_ss"));
            Driver.Log.Save(logPath, Log.Format.Html);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried other solutions like changing the target framework from 4.5 to 4 and 4.5.1.

I am not sure what to do. I am new to VS. Please help

Comment: It looks like you are creating a class `TestLeftTest` that extends `UnitTestClassBase`. The error is saying it doesn't know where `UnitTestClassBase` is, and I don't see it in your code. Where is this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a class with the name `UnitTestClassBase`.

Anyway have a look how to write good unit tests. You should also use the pattern `Arrange, Act and Assert`

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing a reference to the assembly `SmartBear`. To validate this, go to the references in the solution explorer and check this assembly is referenced. If it isn't, add it as a reference.